# Mac OS X Lion: Window has disappeared and won't reappear

Tags: window, osx-lion, hidden, macvim

I'm running the latest version of MacVim on `Mac OS X 10.7.3`.

While editing a file the application decided to hide/shrink its window in some way. It happened in an instant.

I've tried:

- rebooting
- reinstalling
- right-click in dock -> Show All Windows
- in menu bar: Window -> Bring All to Front (this is greyed out as though there *aren't* any windows).

Nothing has brought it back.

I've also tried applescripts to:

- move all hidden windows into visible space
- adjust the size and position of a specified application's window

The second of the above never executed successfully, indicating that the window index I provided (I tried `0`, `1`, `2`) doesn't exist.

Any bright ideas? I'm tearing my hair out right now.

Comment: Have you tried trashing the preference file?

Comment: I don't know what that is, but I'd love to give it a try. I'll google now, but feel free to respond.

Comment: The preference file is in ~/Library/Preferences and will have the name of the application somewhere in the name, and end in `.plist`. See http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/22/access-user-library-folder-in-os-x-lion/ for how to access the Library folder in Lion.

Comment: Thank you for this information Barmar. I've deleted both `/Library/Preferences/*MacVim*` and `/User/me/Library/Preferences/*MacVim*`, verifying the relevant files disappeared after each execution. To my dismay this has had no effect!

Comment: There's a Google Group list for MacVim: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vim_mac

Comment: Yes, thank you for the link. I'll post there and see if anyone can offer a suggestion. I've read online about bugs in Lion with this happening across applications, so thought it likely someone would have a solution on here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd manually removed the Mac OS X inbuilt Ruby version and installed another.

It turns out this had caused the issue.

I identified this by running MacVim manually in Terminal:

```
dave$ /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim
```

As soon as I clicked the icon it displayed in the dock, the terminal displayed the following:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/libruby.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
  Reason: image not found
```

Therefore I recreated the original system inbuilt Ruby directory it referenced:

```
dave$ sudo mkdir -p /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib
```

Then created a symlink from my newer Ruby installation's dynamic library to the location sought by MacVim:

```
dave$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libruby.1.8.7.dylib /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/libruby.1.dylib
```

Now MacVim works fine.